# Could diatomic helium exist?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I know that $\ce{He2}$ (homonuclear diatomic helium) does not exist because its bond order is zero. Since the bond order of $\ce{He2+} = 1/2$, that means that the positive $\ce{He2+}$ ion exists, but how does the positive ion exist if the neutral molecule doesn't?

Comment: It does not last long when formed.

Comment: See [Helium chemistry: a survey of the role of the ionic species. *Int. J. Mass. Spectrom.* **2004,** *237,* 243](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1387380604003094)

Comment: Related: [How can an excited helium dimer be formed?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/why-is-an-excited-helium-dimer-created-in-this-collision-experiment), [Why do noble gases bond with themselves but not other elements?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21820/why-do-noble-gases-bond-with-themselves-but-not-other-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Although we know that the helium dimer has a tiny bond dissociation energy, we don't consider it a molecule, as the "bond" does not survive a molecular vibration, even rotation of the molecule is enough to cleave it.

From an answer by Lighthart on "[Molecular orbital theory & predicting the stability of a molecule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4439/4945)" I took the liberty to borrow the MO schemes:

[image: MO schemes helium dimers]

In the scheme you can clearly see how we arrive at the bond order of zero for $\ce{He2}$. Both, the bonding $\sigma$ and the anti-bonding combination $\sigma^{*}$ are doubly occupied. Dihelium is only held together by weak van der Waals forces.
In the case of the dihelium cation $\ce{He2+}$, one electron is removed from the anti-bonding orbital. There are now more electrons in bonding than anti-bonding orbitals. This effectively results in a net energy loss or bond energy gain, and the overall bond order increases to 0.5. In a more phenomenological context, three negative charges are now in a field of four positive charges, this gives rise to Coulomb attraction.

Reference: [Wikipedia article on dihelium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_dimer#Molecule) and references therein.